# regex match range but not certain characters

Tags: javascript, regex

How do i write regex so it matches A-Z but not characters b,h,i. Only way i could think of is by using custom ranges.

```
/[[A][C-G][J-Z]]/gi
```

This is what i can think of, i don't think this is correct regex, even. i'd like to not write custom ranges if possible. As it's complicate things a lot more.

What  i'm trying to do is make characters increase by one so a becomes b, c -> d, z -> a. Except some words. And this is my strategy... find all words except them, run them through match string and replace them with character that is one ahead using charcode.

Comment: Why do you think that custom ranges would complicate things a lot?

Comment: customization would be harder, error prone, etc

Answer (score 8):

One way is to use negative lookahead:

```
/(?![BHI])[A-Z]/i
```

This will match anything in range `[A-Z]` except characters `B`, `H` and `I`.

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pY8eC7/1)

Comment: Umer: Did this with out?